# How can I access mempool pending transactions without running a full node?

Tags: pending-transactions, txpool

Is there a way to access mempool data without running a full node? through a node provider for example?? (I don't want to use already existing market products (bloXroute, blocknative..), basically I want to build my own from scratch)